# Merging props with HigherOrderComponents

Tags: material-ui

I am looking at https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/1052126cd08f19a04543d829a29f9c30e218a330/docs/src/pages/styles/basics/AdaptingHOC.js#L27

What I want to do is for a Gatsby project do something like this:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(HigherOrderLayout)
```

The problem I am facing is that the component needs a couple of other props.

```
Layout.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.array,
}
```

I am not sure how to provide those other props and I run into the following error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
>   array instead.

I am a complete React n00b so not able to make sense of the help pages. They examples are too simple and I can't find a single example that does what I want to achieve.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code you used that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

- The problem was rendering multiple elements in the render method,
  instead you should wrapped it into a single.
- You could also use     to wrap it in
  a single DOM node.

Seeing an Objects are not valid as a React child error might mean that a few different things are going wrong. For example, it could be because the items being rendered in the JSX Element are objects instead of primitives (so make sure you’re not passing an object where a primitive is expected).